# Prestashop page speed Preload

Tags: prestashop-1.7

in order to make site faster , i use "preload" for stylesheet and javascript files as below :

```html
{foreach $stylesheets.external as $stylesheet}
   
  <link rel="preload" href="{$stylesheet.uri}" as="style">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{$stylesheet.uri}"  media="{$stylesheet.media}">
  
{/foreach}

{foreach $stylesheets.inline as $stylesheet}
  <style>
    {$stylesheet.content}
  </style>
{/foreach}
```

```html
{foreach $javascript.external as $js}
    
  <link rel="preload" href="{$js.uri}" as="script">
  
  <script  src="{$js.uri}" {$js.attribute}></script>
  
{/foreach}

{foreach $javascript.inline as $js}
  <script type="text/javascript">
    {$js.content nofilter}
  </script>
{/foreach}

{if isset($vars) && $vars|@count}
  <script type="text/javascript">
    {foreach from=$vars key=var_name item=var_value}
    var {$var_name} = {$var_value|json_encode nofilter};
    {/foreach}
  </script>
{/if}
```

all css code is in custom.css file and it contains media queries .

for desktop it works well .

How should i modifiy for responsive devices ?

should i put media uery one by one in a separate file ? and how include it in stylesheet.tpl file ?